# How does double dispatch work in Visitor pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, visitor-pattern, double-dispatch

I was looking into other questions related to the visitor pattern but couldn't understand the implementation of double dispatch in visitor pattern.

Please refer to the link 
[Visitor Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/java/2)

How does double dispatch work in the Visitor pattern?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you don't understand?

Comment: Imho you should think to double dispatch as a function overloading at runtime instead of compile time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The element object's `accept` method receives a visitor object and it calls the `visit` method on the visitor object. As the visitor object has several `visit` methods, based on the element type the appropriate `visit` method is called. Here we have two calls (**double dispatch**) that specify the *element* and the right *operation* for the element (based on its type).

Answer (score 60):

**Single-dispatch**

[image: Single dispatch]

Assume Node is an interface class and the two sub classes are concrete implementations of the interface.

If you call `GenerateCode()` method on a node instance, the actual operation getting executed depends on the **type** of the node. It could be the method either in `VariableRefNode` or `AssignmentNode`. It's the same if you call `PrettyPrint()`. So the actual operation getting executed depends on *name of the method* you are calling and the *type of the node*.

**Double-dispatch**

[image: Nodes]
[image: Visitors]

This time the `Node` is allowing you to pass a parameter of type `NodeVisitor` to its method called `Accept`. In your program if you call `Accept` on a node instance, the actual operation getting executed now depends on the *type of the node* (`VariableRefNode` or `AssignmentNode`) **AND** the type of the visitor instance you passed into `Accept` (`TypeCheckingVisitor` or `CodeGeneratingVisitor`).

Answer (score 12):

Well, here's the relevant quote from that article:

> Visitor implements “double dispatch”. OO messages routinely manifest “single dispatch” - the operation that is executed depends on: the name of the request, and the type of the receiver. In “double dispatch”, the operation executed depends on: the name of the request, and the type of TWO receivers (the type of the Visitor and the type of the element it visits).

This essentially means different visitors can visit the same type and different types can be visited by the same visitor. The effect of a named operation that is performed using the visitor pattern may depend on the **visitor *and* the visited** (double dispatch).

Answer (score 4):

An example code, that shows double dispatch:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Node> nodes = Arrays.asList(new NodeA(), new NodeB());
        List<NodeVisitor> visitors = Arrays.asList(new NodeVisitor1(), new NodeVisitor2());

        for (Node node : nodes) {
            for (NodeVisitor visitor : visitors) {
                node.accept(visitor);
            }
        }
    }
}

interface Node {
    void accept(NodeVisitor visitor);
}

interface NodeVisitor {
    void visit(Node node);
}

class NodeA implements Node {

    @Override
    public void accept(NodeVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node A";
    }
}

class NodeB implements Node {

    @Override
    public void accept(NodeVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node B";
    }
}

class NodeVisitor1 implements NodeVisitor {

    @Override
    public void visit(Node node) {
        System.out.println("Node visitor 1, node " + node);
    }
}

class NodeVisitor2 implements NodeVisitor {

    @Override
    public void visit(Node node) {
        System.out.println("Node visitor 2, node " + node);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Node visitor 1, node Node A
Node visitor 2, node Node A
Node visitor 1, node Node B
Node visitor 2, node Node B
```