# Storing Objects of multiple classes in an Array List, then accessing their attributes

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have class of (sub)Objects

```
public class SubObjects {
    
    int depth;
    
    public SubObjects(int d) {
        this.depth = d;
    }
}
```

And a class of Objects

```
public class Objects {
    
    private int height;
    private int width;
    ArrayList<SubObjects> liste;
    
    public Objects(int h, int w) {
        this.height = h;
        this.width = w;
        this.liste = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

The Objects hold the values height and width and an ArrayList of SubObjects. This works as intended, I do however want to store multiple types of SubObjects from different classes in these ArrayLists.

After a bit of googling I changed the Objects class to

```
public class Objects {
    
    private int height;
    private int width;
    ArrayList<Object> liste;
    
    public Objects(int h, int w) {
        this.height = h;
        this.width = w;
        this.liste = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
}
```

This allows me, as I intended, to store Objects from a second class SubObjects2 inside the ArrayList

```
public class SubObjects2 {
    
    int weight;
    
    public SubObjects2(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

This was great and I thought I had solved it, but then I ran the main class and while I, with the earlier implementation could return values with a getter from the objects in the ArrayList

```
... liste.get(i).depth (in a for loop)
```

The same query now returns the following error

```
Unresolved compilation problem: 
    depth cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

How do I access the values inside the SubObjects that are stored in the ArrayList now?

Comment: Instead of `int depth` use `public int depth`

Comment: What's the difference between Objects and SubObjects?  Why do they have s?  Are they a collection of things? O r a single thing?  Is SubObject related to Object?  Maybe you mean to make SubObject extends Object?  Object is made of other objects or subobjects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `Object` class has no field with the name `depth` and only `SubObject` has this attribute

If all of your types have common attributes that you want to get it, you can create an interface and all of them should implement it it for example

```java
interface SubObject {
    int value();
}

public class SubObjects implements SubObject {

    ...

    @Override
    public int value() {
        return depth;
    }
}

public class SubObjects2 implements SubObject {

    ...

    @Override
    public int value() {
        return weight;
    }
}
```

and now you will create a list of SubObject and in the loop, it will be

```java
for (int i = 0; i < lists.size() ; i++) {
    int value = lists.get(i).value();
}
```

The other solution is to check for the type and cast it before getting the value for example

```java
List<Object> lists = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0 ; i < lists.size(); i++) {
    Object object = lists.get(i);
    if (object.getClass() == SubObjects.class) {
        SubObjects subObject = (SubObjects) object;
        int depth = subObject.depth;
    }
    
    else if if (object.getClass() == SubObjects2.class) {
        SubObjects2 subObject2 = (SubObjects2) object;
        int weight = subObject2.weight;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another solution for the case where the SubObjects do not implement a common interface is to use the Visitor pattern, which is slightly more complex, but avoids the reflection required for Object.getClass(). See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762256/how-does-double-dispatch-work-in-visitor-pattern

Comment: I assume just renaming the field in SubObjects2 to 'depth' as well won't cut it?

Comment: without a common interface, you will need to check if it is SubObjects or SubObjects2 then cast it and get depth, you can name the interface method `depth` or `getDepth` and use it

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explaining these two lines a bit more: SubObjects subObject = (SubObjects) object;
        int depth = subObject.depth;

Comment: The first line will cast object from `Object` type to your `SubObjects` type and now you can use it like any other SubObjects and get depth from it

Comment: Got it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there's no relationships between two classes other than that they both extend Object class which all objects do and you want to store objects of those two classes in the same list, you can store them in a list of objects.

Before you can access attributes of the object, you need to cast it to the type you want to use.  This is how it's done before generics.

```
        List list = new ArrayList(List.of(Integer.valueOf(1), "hello"));
        
        for(Object o: list){
            if (o instanceof Integer){
                System.out.println("o is an integer.");
                Integer i = (Integer) o;
                System.out.println(i.intValue());
            } else if (o instanceof String){
                System.out.println("o is a string.");
                String s = (String) o;
                System.out.println(s.length());
        }
    }
```